# 401 on every CRUD .net Framework API

Tags: c#, .net, angular, jwt

So I have a project, its a .net framework api and an angular front end.

I recently added OWIN JWT authentication but it seems that anything I do returns a 401 error. And I have tried 100's of solutions to no success.

When I login the JWT is correcly passed through to the frontend.

My startup.cs

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.Jwt;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Owin;

[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(AgriLogBackend.Startup))]

namespace AgriLogBackend
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(
                new JwtBearerAuthenticationOptions
                {
                    AuthenticationMode = Microsoft.Owin.Security.AuthenticationMode.Active,
                    TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
                    {
                        ValidateIssuer = true,
                        ValidateAudience = true,
                        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                          
                        
                        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("GuessThePassword----"))
                    }
                });
        }
    }
}
```

My controller has the [Authorize] attribute.

And I do pass the correct JWT back to the controllers but it seems that its failing to authorise.

Any help is greatly appreciated

In angular I use a post like this:

```
const ops = {     // <<<<<< Initialize header with token
        headers: new HttpHeaders({
          
          'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem("jwtToken")
        })
      };
        return this.http.get<types>(this.baseURL + "EquipmentTypes/" + localStorage.getItem("currentFarm"),ops);
```

Creating the token in c#:

```
 public IHttpActionResult Login(User user)
            {
                var finduser = db.Users.Where(x => x.User_Email == user.User_Email).FirstOrDefault();

                var encPass = encrypt(user.User_Password);
                if (finduser != null && finduser.User_Password == encPass)
                {
                    var claims = new[]
                    {
                   new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name,finduser.User_ID.ToString())



                };
                    var keytoReturn = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_key));

                    var Credentials = new SigningCredentials(keytoReturn, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha512Signature);
                    var descriptorToken = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
                    {
                        Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(claims),
                        Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1),
                        SigningCredentials = Credentials
                    };
                    var Handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();

                    var userToken = Handler.CreateToken(descriptorToken);
                    return Ok
                    (new
                    {
                        Token = Handler.WriteToken(userToken)
                    }
                    );

                }

                return Unauthorized();

            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You setup the `TokenValidationParameters` like this:

```
TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
{
    ValidateIssuer = true,
    ValidateAudience = true,
    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("GuessThePassword----"))
}
```

which tells the JwtBearerAuthentication middleware to check every token for valid issuer and audience claims (`iss` and `aud` in the token).

As you did not add both claims during the creation of the token, the verification will fail. Your choice is either to turn the options off:

```
ValidateIssuer = false,
ValidateAudience = false,
```

so that these checks are not performed, or add proper claims for them when you create the token:

```
var descriptorToken = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
{
    Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(claims),
    Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1),
    SigningCredentials = Credentials
    TokenIssuerName = "YourIssuer",                // add your issuer here
    AppliesToAddress = "YourAudience",             // add your audience here
};
var Handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
var userToken = Handler.CreateToken(descriptorToken);
```

Reference for [SecurityTokenDescriptor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.identitymodel.tokens.securitytokendescriptor?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8)